# Error in running sfLapply in R

Tags: r, snowfall

My piece of code looks like:

```
x<- c(1,2,3,4,5)

library(snowfall)

f1<- function(a,list){
  f2<-function(b,num){ return(abs(num-b))}

  l1<-sfLapply(list, f2, num=a)
  l1<-sum(unlist(l1))
  return(l1)
}

sfInit(parallel=TRUE,cpus=4)
l2<-(sfLapply(x, f1, list=x))
sfStop()
l2
```

when I run the last four lines, it gives an error:

```
l2<-(sfLapply(x, f1, list=x))
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  4 nodes produced errors; first error: could not find function "sfLapply"
```

When I switch to sequential processing, using lapply, it runs perfectly.

```
> l2<-(lapply(x, f1, list=x))
> l2
[[1]]
[1] 10

[[2]]
[1] 7

[[3]]
[1] 6

[[4]]
[1] 7

[[5]]
[1] 10
```

Why is sfLapply throwing an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load the `snowfall` package on the cluster nodes. So insert

```
sfLibrary(snowfall)
```

after `sfInit()`.

---

**EDIT:** For clarification:

Your function `f1` contains the function `sfLapply`, which is found in the `snowfall` package. When you initialize the cluster using `sfInit` as above, the `snow` package is loaded on each node of the cluster, but not the `snowfall` package. Without the latter, there is no object (function or otherwise) called `sfLapply` on the nodes, and you get the error.

Comment: Thanks! Could you also please explain the working of this? I've used sfLapply before with multiple cores but never got this error.

Comment: @jackStinger, does the edit explain things enough? Can you replace `sfLapply` in the `f1` function with `lapply`?